# Request permission dialog box is not popping up in Android Marshmallow

Tags: android

My app requires the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
```

Until lollipop it was working fine but starting with Marshmallow, I need to ask for permission at runtime. So, I used this code:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    //my code here   
} else {
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission is requird",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW},REQUEST_RESULT);
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String[] permissions,int[] grantResult){
    if (requestCode==REQUEST_RESULT){
        if (grantResult[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //my code here
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"permission has not granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResult);
    }
}
```

When I try to run the app, the request permission dialog box does not appear and display a message saying "permission has not been granted". Why is the request permission dialog box is not appearing?

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.adarsh.ezswipe"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES` does not need to be requested at runtime, as its `protectionLevel` is not `dangerous`.

`SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` cannot be requested at runtime through this mechanism. Please [use `canDrawOverlays()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#canDrawOverlays(android.content.Context)) and `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION`.

Comment: OK then to request permission in marshmallow device I have to use   canDrawOverlays()

Comment: I have already tried this but it doesn't show that permissions is not requested in app info of my app.But the permission you suggested works perfectly but it gives me some errors in locating like this:  E / Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7519c0 what is it